# Where is this image coming from?

Tags: materials, shaders, eevee-render-engine

If I create a new blender file, switch to "lookdev" view and apply the glass shader to an object, this happens:

[image: blender scene with cube with glass shader]

Where is the image of the reflection coming from? It is a brand new file so it wasn't me who added it, I'm so confused.